# Win32 Project (API): Compatibility with other version of Windows

Tags: api, winapi, compatibility

I use API to make a  programs. It runs pretty well on Windows 7 (with debug file .exe), but it doesn't when I run it on Windows XP. Are there any ways to solve this problem?

Comment: What happens when you run it in XP? I.e. do you get some message box? What compiler and version is the program built with? Is it a 32-bit or 64-bit program?

Comment: A message box appear. it said that "This application has failed to start because MSVCR100D.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem".

Comment: You need to install the [Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8328) on your XP machine. See [this discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/3c9a5b9b-1a7d-4d86-bc82-85652448e0c9) for more details.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Is there anything to do or code with VS 2010 to debug for a program that can run well on Windows XP, Windows 7, even Windows 8?

Comment: Unless you build an installer to install all of your program dependency's you will need to do as Remy states and install them yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are using Visual C++, according the the message you get.

Your project is set up (by default) to link the Microsoft C++ Runtime Librairy dynamically, so it saves up space in your final executable, but you need the dynamic linked libraries to be in your system or in your executable's folder.

To solve this in Visual C++, without any afford from who are executing the program in their machines, you can change how MSVC link their runtime library to your executable, that is, if you set it to be linked statically, all the dependencies will be linked inside your final `.exe`, with no need of additional `.dll`s.

To change this option, refer to [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3%28v=vs.100%29).

Or in short: <kbd>Project Properties</kbd>><kbd>Configuration Properties</kbd>><kbd>C/C++</kbd>><kbd>Code Generation</kbd>><kbd>Runtime Library</kbd>

If in debug mode, use `/MTd`, otherwise use `/MT`.